# LINQ to SQL - PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, predicatebuilder

Quick question on how to get even more out of PredicateBuilder. It works as per below:

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

The question is, what if I would like to search by an arbitrary member as well, ie pass the function string[] as the keywords, but also the field to search by, eg fieldToSearch, and replace the p=> p.Description.Contains(temp)); with something allowing searching by fieldToSearch?

Is this possible, is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) might be more appropriate.

> While writing type-safe queries is
>   great for most scenarios, there are
>   cases where you want the flexibility
>   to dynamically construct queries on
>   the fly.  For example: you might want
>   to provide business intelligence UI
>   within your application that allows an
>   end-user business analyst to use
>   drop-downs to build and express their
>   own custom queries/views on top of
>   data.
>
> Traditionally these types of dynamic
>   query scenarios are often handled by
>   concatenating strings together to
>   construct dynamic SQL queries. 
>   Recently a few people have sent me
>   mail asking how to handle these types
>   of scenarios using LINQ.  The below
>   post describes how you can use a
>   Dynamic Query Library provided by the
>   LINQ team to dynamically construct
>   LINQ queries.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a separate method that takes an `Expression<Func<Product,bool>>` as a parameter.  Then build the predicate outside the method and pass it as a parameter.

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (Expression<Func<Product,bool>> selector )
{
    return dataContext.Products.Where( selector );
}
```

used as

```
var selector = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>()
                               .Or( p => p.Name == name )
                               .Or( p => p.Vendor == vendor );

products = repository.SearchProducts( selector );
```